# What does it mean by triangle normal to a plane?

Tags: vectors

Question:

2 lines and they intersect at point $P(1,-1,2)$ and the cartesian equation of the plane $A$that contains the 2 lines is given by $2x-y+z-5=0$.

The point $Q(3,4,3)$ lies on the plan $A$. The line $L$ passes thorugh the midpoint of $PQ$. Point $S$ is on $L$ such that $|\vec {PQ}|$ = $|\vec {QS}|$ = $3$, and the triangle $PQS$ is normal to the plane $A$. Given that there are $2$ possible positions for $S$, find their coordinates.

Now I already completed this question and I am not asking anyone to do it for me and I have the answer.

My question is how can I visualise a triangle normal to the plane? How does "shape" normal to plane mean?

Is the triangle perpendicular to the normal of the plane? Does that mean the normal of the triangle is perpendicular to the normal of the plane? Can someone Draw a diagram for this?

Comment: Yes normal vectors of the given plane and the plane that has the triangle are perpendicular to each other (their dot product will be zero)

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes a picture is worth a thousand words:

There was a complaint that my previous figure wasn't "perfectly clear."  Here are three views, where I've added in red orthogonal axes, two within the plane, one perpendicular:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Clear now?

Comment: Thanks for answering, so the triangle is not perpendicular to the plane? The triangle lies of the plane?

Comment: @Nhoj_Gonk, draw a triangle on cover page of a notebook. Now hold the notebook perpendicular to table surface. You'll see that the drawn triangle is perpendicular/normal to the plane of table surface. What can you conclude?

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for the update.

Comment: Thank you Mr.Stork!

Answer (score 0):

[image: SEE WHAT I MEADE FOR YOU]

The rectangular box is your Plane A $2x−y+z−5=0$ while L1, L2 are two lines that intersect at point P as shown while Q lies on plane A.

The line L is perpendicular to plane A since the ΔPQS is normal to A abd given S lies on L.

Observe that ΔPQS is now normal to that plane A.

Note: The other possibility of the triangle is on opposite side of what I made you can imagine that by rotating that triangle by 180 degree either clockwise or anticlockwise.

I hope you may have a clear picture now in your mind !!

Comment: Thanks for answering, so $p$,$Q$ and $m$ lie on the plane?

Comment: See it has been told that $L1 , L2$ lies on plane so there $POI$ will also lie on the plane (you can even put $P$ in plane $A$ equation to verify), $Q$ has been already  given that it lies on the Plane $A$ and finally the mid point M will definitely lie on that plane since it is a point over that line $PQ$.